# Could not save data in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6

I am new to core data , in order to add data

in xcode 6.1.1 using swift

this button function should take username and password from two text fields and save them

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newUser.setValue(""+username.text, forKey: "username")
    newUser.setValue(password.text, forKey: "password")

    context.save(nil)

    println(newUser)
    println("Object Saved")

    }
```

this code compile, how ever it has a run time error

ones I click on it I see this error

> 2015-01-26 21:40:55.160 cordatafirst[2104:1324567] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null)

MY AppDelegate.swift file

```
    //
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  cordatafirst
//
//  Created by Mustafa on 1/26/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Rashwan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "edu.self.cordatafirst" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("cordatafirst", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("cordatafirst.sqlite")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
            coordinator = nil
            // Report any error we got.
            let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
            error = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator == nil {
            return nil
        }
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
            var error: NSError? = nil
            if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You have cordatafirst.sqlite are you sure you don't need coredatafirst.sqlite

Comment: Sorry I did not get your comment

Comment: Have you misspelt the name of the CoreData model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your persistent store is not added. Does your AppDelegate look like [THIS](https://github.com/jquave/Core-Data-In-Swift-Tutorial/blob/Part3/MyLog/AppDelegate.swift) ? (I've got this file from [THIS](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/) tutorial, but it's essentially the same among most apps)

Comment: I is exactly the same "Not Changed"

Comment: Did you replace your own with this one? Could you please paste your COMPLETE AppDelegate code in your question?

Comment: I have pasted my COMPLETE AppDelegate code in my question
hope that could help ... thanks

Comment: Ok, and have you tried deleting the app from the simulator and rebuilding it? With CoreData, when things get messed up with persistent stores, you have to delete the app and rebuild it. (Which you should note how and when that happens, since you don't want it to happen to real users)

Comment: Yea man I worked 

Many thanks although I still do not know where is the error.... After I deleted the app and run again it works

Comment: haha i'm glad I could help. I strongly recommend reading heavily on how persistent stores and coredata models work and how you can update them because it's very easy to break it, and users will lose all their data!